# Remote camera application

Tags: camera

I am brand new to RPi. I want to create a remote camera (assumed based on RPi 0 W) that will serve as a camera on the back of my travel trailer so I can see what is behind me as I go down the road, transmitting the image to my phone in my truck. Hence no router available.

A solution I considering is to create an Ad Hoc server on the RPi 0 W, install RPi_Cam_Web_Interface and view images from my phone over a browser. Alternatively, instead of RPi_Cam_Web_Interface, I could install an SSH server on the RPi and use VNC viewer on my phone.

Suggestions on either approach, or a better approach is appreciated.

Comment: if the camera can act as an AP and serves a web page with the image, then you could use a web browser

Comment: May be worth trying the solution before fitting as the last thing you want is any delay.  Even a second could allow someone to dash behind you and I think it would be tempting to use this as a reversing camera even if you do not start out with that aim...